# jQuery, finding child div having no id no class but with text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div>
    <div> 
        <div> 
            <div>
                <div> I am here </div> 
                <div> Another div</div>
                <div> Find me I am here </div>
            </div> 
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to hide the div having text "**Find me I am here**"

```
 <script language="t" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {       
    $("div:contains('Find me i am here')").css("display","none");
});
</script>
```

But the above code does not work for me? 
Please help. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use an `if` condition with [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to do so, would be even precise than using `:contains()` because `:contains()` will look for that text even if it's withing another string, so that will even match something like

```
<div>Hey I don't want to hide this Find me i am here</div>
```

[Ummm you don't need that right?](http://jsfiddle.net/mP5Yz/3/) <sup>Credit for fiddle : @Arun P Johny</sup>

So you can refer the solutions below..

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('div').each(function() {
        if($(this).html() == ' Find me i am here ') {
            $(this).css({'display': 'none'});
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YSkE9/)

---

Note: I am having a space before and after the string in the `if` condition for comparison, as it matters, if you want to make it less stricter, then use `.trim()` for chopping of the white space from beginning and end of your string.

---

Also, if you are looking to target the elements having that text but having **NO** `class` or `id` attributes, than use the code below

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('div:not([class]):not([id]').each(function() { 
        //Select only div which doesn't have class or id attributes
        if($(this).html() == ' Find me i am here ') {
            $(this).css({'display': 'none'});
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/YSkE9/8/)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy may be :)

Comment: I am just searching for the text and there is of course no html in that div, so, i have changed .html() to .text() in your code and it's now really working for me. thanks dude

Comment: @AbdulRahman Oops, I made a mistake there, should be `.text()` and you welcome :)

Comment: @AbdulRahman actually that will be even stricter, so I won't change, it's like mistake went correct hehe

Comment: Ya, you are right, but in this situation i have only a static text and nothing else. :))

Answer (score 2):

because it will return all ancestor divs also, you need to filter out divs with children from the set returned by `:contains`

```
$("div:contains('Find me i am here'):not(:has(*))").hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mP5Yz/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a callback function to `.html()` method itself

`data` holds html content inside the div and then compare it with the text your searching.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {     
   $('div').html(function(t,data) {
       if(data ===' Find me i am here ')
        $(this).css("display","none");
   });
});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YSkE9/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:contains` to get element, see the below code.

```
$('div:contains("test")').hide();
```